# List Find ,Hashset Or Linq Which One is Better On list

Tags: linq, list, c#-3.0

I Have a list of string where i want to find particular value and return.
If i just want to search i can use Hashset instead of list

```
 HashSet<string> data = new HashSet<string>();    
 bool contains = data.Contains("lokendra"); //
```

But for list i am using `Find` because i want to return the value also from list.
I found this methos  is time consuming. The method where this code resides is `hit more than 1000 times` and the size of list is appx `20000 to 25000`.This method takes time.Is there any other way i can make search faster.

```
List<Employee> employeeData= new List<Employee>();
var  result = employeeData.Find(element=>element.name=="lokendra")
```

Do we have any linq or any other approach which makes retrievel of data faster from search.
Please help.

```
 public struct Employee
    {
        public string role;
        public string id;
        public int salary;
        public string name;  
        public string address;          
    }
```

I have the list of this structure and if the name property matches the value "lokendra".then i want to retrun the whole object.Consider list as the employee data.

I want to know the way we have Hashset to get faster search is there anyway we can search data and return fast other than find.

Comment: What do you mean by "i want to return the value also from list"? You know the value - you're checking for it, so it will always be "lokendra". Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Jon Skeet. I want to find from the list if the list contains the value or not actually its a list of objects so if name property matches then i will return the whole object.

Comment: That completely changes the nature of the question. Your actual situation doesn't match the one you've described.

Comment: Just wanted to know the performance in my case did not wanted to post code from project so took simple similar scenario. Sorry  Jon Skeet..

Comment: But the point is it's *not* similar. In the case you described in your question, a `HashSet` would have been fine.

Comment: I pointed out that Hashset is faster if i just want to search do we have anything similar that makes searching faster and also retrieves values..

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you *actually* want is a `Dictionary<string, Employee>`. Build that once, and you can query it efficiently many times. You can build it from a list of employees easily:

```
var employeesByName = employees.ToDictionary(e => e.Name);
...

var employee;
if (employeesByName.TryGetValue(name, out employee))
{
    // Yay, found the employee
}
else
{
    // Nope, no employee with that name
}
```

EDIT: Now I've seen your edit... *please* don't create `struct` types like this. You almost certainly want a `class` instead, and one with properties rather than public fields...

Comment: Can i match both name and id because there can be two employees with same name.How to do that?

Comment: @lokendrajayaswal: I'm not going to keep updating my answer as you refine the requirements. I suggest you delete this question and then ask a new one with *all* your requirements... otherwise it's just pointless.

Comment: I tried deleting this.But does not work however your first answer suffice my requirement in other scenario where i want to just check whether list contains the table Name from Database.that is pretty fast now..Will ask new question on the same.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet Sir i hav ereposted the question please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `employeeData.FirstOrDefault(e => e == "lokendra")`, but it still needs to iterate over collection, so will have performance list `Find` method.

If your list content is set only once and then you're searching it again and again you should consider implementing your own solution:

- sort list before first search
- use binary search (which would be *O(log n)* instead of *O(n)* for standard `Find` and `Where`)

Comment: You are right MarcinJuraszek.. I tried this but the performance is same.

Comment: @ MarcinJuraszek.Actually i have the list of objects.Where if one property matches the Value passed to it.then whole object would be returned.

Comment: OK, but does your list content change between searches?

Comment: I have list where the contents are getting added if the data is not found in the lis and one scenario  where only search take place in the list both are different list..